# $k$ wave number expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have a wave function $\psi(x,t)$ and its fourier transform $\phi(k,t)$.

**Question:** Can I calculate the expectation value of $\hat{k}$?

I mean, doing the weighted average in $k$ space like this:

$$\langle \hat{k} \rangle = \int \phi^{*}\;\hat{k}\;\phi\; dk$$

Comment: What does the hat $\hat k$ on your $k$ mean? I think it should not be there.

Comment: $\hat{k}$ it's an operator like this: $\hat{k}\phi = k\phi$.

Comment: Then Youe equation for $\langle k\rangle$ is wrong. I will write out a proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important not to confuse operators, states, and wavefunctions.

Let us have a state $|\psi\rangle$ with position-basis wavefunction $\langle x|\psi\rangle= \psi(x)$. Inserting a complete set of momentum eigenstates $|k\rangle$, or equivalently   expressing the identity operator as
$$
{\mathbb I}=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} |k\rangle \langle k |,
$$
we can write
$$
\langle x|\psi\rangle = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} \langle x|k\rangle \langle k |\psi\rangle= \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} e^{ikx} \phi(k)
$$
where $\phi(k)= \langle k|\psi\rangle$ is the wavefunction for the state $|\psi\rangle$ in the momentum basis, and $\langle x|k\rangle = e^{ikx}$ is the wavefunction for the state $|k\rangle$ in the $x$ basis.

Now recall that in the $x$ basis the momentum opertor $\hat p$ acts as
$$
\langle x|\hat p|\psi\rangle = -i\partial_x \langle x|\psi\rangle
$$
but in the momentum  basis we have the much simpler
$$
\langle k |\hat p|\psi\rangle= k \langle k|\psi\rangle.
$$
So again using
$$
{\mathbb I}=\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} |k\rangle \langle k |
$$
we can write
$$
\langle \psi|\hat p|\psi\rangle = \int \frac{dk}{2\pi}\langle \psi|\hat p|k\rangle  \langle k|\psi\rangle\\ =\int \frac{dk}{2\pi} k\langle \psi|k\rangle  \langle k|\psi\rangle= \int \frac{dk}{2\pi} k \phi^*(k)\phi(k).
$$
There is no hat on the $k$ in this last expression because it is a number not an operator.